# python manipulating a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still trying to find an approach and thinking about the best way to start. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything comparable on the internet - maybe you can give me some tips.

For this purpose, I have created a small example data set; initial situation:

[image]

I would like to prepare the data in a certain way, so that lengths for classes (C1 to C4) are continuously added up - and that the POSITION field on the one hand and the NUMBER field on the other serve as "separation". I think a picture describes it better:

[image]

The lengths are determined accordingly with (END - START).

Here is the Excel file: https://easyupload.io/vb86lh
Click on the button here (not on the other stuff):
[image]

This is my beginning so far:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 
    'CLASS': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'NUMBER': [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
    'START': [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900],
    'END': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000],
    'POSITION': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'VALUE': [4.4, 3.8, 3.7, 2.9, 1.7, 1.7, 2.8, 2.0, 2.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.9, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.3, 1.3, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9, 3.6, 2.9, 2.2, 1.6, 1.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.7, 3.6, 4.0, 3.6, 4.1, 5.0, 3.9]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for number in df['NUMBER'].unique().tolist():

    print('to do')
```

As you can see, I am not yet sure how best to approach the whole thing. I'm not sure if I have to work with .groupby() or if I have to iterate through the dataframe, or even both. Do you have any tips?

Im still trying to find an efficient approach. Do you have any advise?

Comment: What means "classes (C1 to C4)"? The "class" column only contains "C" everywhere.

Comment: this looks like it could be a rather simple question, but what are you trying to achieve please ?

Comment: C1 to C4 contain the lengths of each row. So it should sum all rows within the desired grouping for the respective values. So for the first row in output it has 300 meters in C1 because there are three sections within the first group and 400 meters in C2, etc.

C is basicly just a letter assigned for the rows, so it should only take a unique value of that.

Comment: maybe first find `"working"` solution instead of `"the best"` solution because at this moment you have nothing.

Comment: first idea is to use `groupby("POSITION")` but rather it can create only two groups `A` and `B` (with all `A` in first, and all `B` in second) and I don't see other column which could split it. I would rather try to iterate and check if next row has different `POSITION` to create new list to get next group. It would need to use `.shift()` to get current POSITION and next POSITION in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is to group it.

Standard `groupby("POSITION")` in `pandas` would create only two groups: `A` (with all `A`) and `B` (with all `B`) and it can't split these groups when `POSITION` change value. And I don't see other column which could help.

But `itertools.groupby()` creates expected groups

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 
    'CLASS': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'NUMBER': [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
    'START': [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900],
    'END': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000],
    'POSITION': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'VALUE': [4.4, 3.8, 3.7, 2.9, 1.7, 1.7, 2.8, 2.0, 2.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.9, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.3, 1.3, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9, 3.6, 2.9, 2.2, 1.6, 1.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.7, 3.6, 4.0, 3.6, 4.1, 5.0, 3.9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# it creates only two groups
#for val, grp in df.groupby('POSITION', sort=False):
#    print(val)
    
import itertools 

for (position, number), group in itertools.groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda item:(item[1]['POSITION'], item[1]['NUMBER']) ):
    rows = (item[1] for item in group)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print(new_df)
    print('---')
```

gives

```
   ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
0   1     C      21      0   100        A    4.4
1   2     C      21    100   200        A    3.8
2   3     C      21    200   300        A    3.7
3   4     C      21    300   400        A    2.9
4   5     C      21    400   500        A    1.7
5   6     C      21    500   600        A    1.7
6   7     C      21    600   700        A    2.8
7   8     C      21    700   800        A    2.0
8   9     C      21    800   900        A    2.5
9  10     C      21    900  1000        A    1.6
---
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
10  11     C      21   1000  1100        B    1.9
11  12     C      21   1100  1200        B    2.9
12  13     C      21   1200  1300        B    2.7
13  14     C      21   1300  1400        B    2.8
14  15     C      21   1400  1500        B    3.5
15  16     C      21   1500  1600        B    3.5
16  17     C      21   1600  1700        B    2.7
---
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
17  18     C      21   1700  1800        A    2.8
18  19     C      21   1800  1900        A    3.5
19  20     C      21   1900  2000        A    3.5
---
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
20  21     C      22   2000  2100        A    2.7
21  22     C      22   2100  2200        A    2.3
22  23     C      22   2200  2300        A    1.3
23  24     C      22   2300  2400        A    3.5
---
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
24  25     C      22   2400  2500        B    3.6
25  26     C      22   2500  2600        B    3.9
26  27     C      22   2600  2700        B    3.6
27  28     C      22   2700  2800        B    2.9
28  29     C      22   2800  2900        B    2.2
29  30     C      22   2900  3000        B    1.6
30  31     C      22   3000  3100        B    1.1
31  32     C      22   3100  3200        B    3.6
32  33     C      22   3200  3300        B    3.9
---
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE
33  34     C      22   3300  3400        A    3.7
34  35     C      22   3400  3500        A    3.6
35  36     C      22   3500  3600        A    4.0
36  37     C      22   3600  3700        A    3.6
37  38     C      22   3700  3800        A    4.1
38  39     C      22   3800  3900        A    5.0
39  40     C      22   3900  4000        A    3.9
---
```

Next step is to count "colors" in `VALUE` but it can be simpler if I create new column with `C1`,`C2`, `C3`,`C4`.

```
df['COLOR'] = 'C0'  # default value at start

df.loc[ (4 <= df['VALUE']), 'COLOR'] = 'C4'
df.loc[ (3 <= df['VALUE']) & (df['VALUE'] < 4), 'COLOR' ] = 'C3'
df.loc[ (2 <= df['VALUE']) & (df['VALUE'] < 3), 'COLOR' ] = 'C2'
df.loc[ (df['VALUE'] < 2), 'COLOR' ] = 'C1'
```

```
    ID CLASS  NUMBER  START   END POSITION  VALUE COLOR
0    1     C      21      0   100        A    4.4    C4
1    2     C      21    100   200        A    3.8    C3
2    3     C      21    200   300        A    3.7    C3
3    4     C      21    300   400        A    2.9    C2
4    5     C      21    400   500        A    1.7    C1
5    6     C      21    500   600        A    1.7    C1
6    7     C      21    600   700        A    2.8    C2
7    8     C      21    700   800        A    2.0    C2
8    9     C      21    800   900        A    2.5    C2
9   10     C      21    900  1000        A    1.6    C1
10  11     C      21   1000  1100        B    1.9    C1
11  12     C      21   1100  1200        B    2.9    C2
12  13     C      21   1200  1300        B    2.7    C2
13  14     C      21   1300  1400        B    2.8    C2
14  15     C      21   1400  1500        B    3.5    C3
15  16     C      21   1500  1600        B    3.5    C3
16  17     C      21   1600  1700        B    2.7    C2
17  18     C      21   1700  1800        A    2.8    C2
18  19     C      21   1800  1900        A    3.5    C3
19  20     C      21   1900  2000        A    3.5    C3
20  21     C      22   2000  2100        A    2.7    C2
21  22     C      22   2100  2200        A    2.3    C2
22  23     C      22   2200  2300        A    1.3    C1
23  24     C      22   2300  2400        A    3.5    C3
24  25     C      22   2400  2500        B    3.6    C3
25  26     C      22   2500  2600        B    3.9    C3
26  27     C      22   2600  2700        B    3.6    C3
27  28     C      22   2700  2800        B    2.9    C2
28  29     C      22   2800  2900        B    2.2    C2
29  30     C      22   2900  3000        B    1.6    C1
30  31     C      22   3000  3100        B    1.1    C1
31  32     C      22   3100  3200        B    3.6    C3
32  33     C      22   3200  3300        B    3.9    C3
33  34     C      22   3300  3400        A    3.7    C3
34  35     C      22   3400  3500        A    3.6    C3
35  36     C      22   3500  3600        A    4.0    C4
36  37     C      22   3600  3700        A    3.6    C3
37  38     C      22   3700  3800        A    4.1    C4
38  39     C      22   3800  3900        A    5.0    C4
39  40     C      22   3900  4000        A    3.9    C3
```

And next I can count colors in every group and multiply by 100

And in group I can add `START` and `END` (and other values)

```
result = pd.DataFrame()

for (position, number), group in itertools.groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda item:(item[1]['POSITION'], item[1]['NUMBER']) ):
    rows = (item[1] for item in group)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    #print(new_df)
    
    count = new_df['COLOR'].value_counts()*100
    
    count['CLASS'] = 'C'
    count['POSITION'] = position
    count['START'] = new_df['START'].min()
    count['END'] = new_df['END'].max()
    count['SERIAL'] = number % 10
    #print(count)
    
    result = result.append(count, ignore_index=True)
    #print('---')
```

After creating `result` it needs to fill empty places, set type `int` and change order of columns

```
# fill empty cell
result = result.fillna(0)

# set type `int`
result[['C1','C2','C3','C4','START','END','SERIAL']] = result[['C1','C2','C3','C4','START','END','SERIAL']].astype(int)

# change columns order
result = result[['CLASS','SERIAL','START','END','POSITION','C1','C2','C3','C4']]

print(result)
```

Final result:

```
  CLASS  SERIAL  START   END POSITION   C1   C2   C3   C4
0     C       1      0  1000        A  300  400  200  100
1     C       1   1000  1700        B  100  400  200    0
2     C       1   1700  2000        A    0  100  200    0
3     C       2   2000  2400        A  100  200  100    0
4     C       2   2400  3300        B  200  200  500    0
5     C       2   3300  4000        A    0    0  400  300
```

---

If `end - start` can be different than 100 then you can create column

```
df['LENGTH'] = df['END'] - df['START']
```

and later group by `COLOR` and sum `LENGTH`

```
count = new_df.groupby('COLOR')['LENGTH'].sum()
```

**EDIT:** I added this to code.

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools 

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 
    'CLASS': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'NUMBER': [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
    'START': [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900],
    'END': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000],
    'POSITION': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'VALUE': [4.4, 3.8, 3.7, 2.9, 1.7, 1.7, 2.8, 2.0, 2.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.9, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.8, 3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 2.3, 1.3, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9, 3.6, 2.9, 2.2, 1.6, 1.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.7, 3.6, 4.0, 3.6, 4.1, 5.0, 3.9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#for val, grp in df.groupby('POSITION', sort=False):
#    print(val)

df['COLOR'] = 'C0'  # default value at start

df.loc[ (df['VALUE'] < 2), 'COLOR' ] = 'C1'
df.loc[ (2 <= df['VALUE']) & (df['VALUE'] < 3), 'COLOR' ] = 'C2'
df.loc[ (3 <= df['VALUE']) & (df['VALUE'] < 4), 'COLOR' ] = 'C3'
df.loc[ (4 <= df['VALUE']), 'COLOR'] = 'C4'

df['LENGTH'] = df['END'] - df['START']

#print(df)

result = pd.DataFrame()

for (position, number), group in itertools.groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda item:(item[1]['POSITION'], item[1]['NUMBER']) ):
    rows = (item[1] for item in group)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    #print(new_df)
    
    #count = new_df['COLOR'].value_counts()*100
    count = new_df.groupby('COLOR')['LENGTH'].sum()

    count['CLASS'] = 'C'
    count['POSITION'] = position
    count['START'] = new_df['START'].min()
    count['END'] = new_df['END'].max()
    count['SERIAL'] = number % 10
    #print(count)
    
    result = result.append(count, ignore_index=True)
    #print('---')

# fill empty cells
result = result.fillna(0)

# set type `int`
result[['C1','C2','C3','C4','START','END','SERIAL']] = result[['C1','C2','C3','C4','START','END','SERIAL']].astype(int)

# change columns order
result = result[['CLASS','SERIAL','START','END','POSITION','C1','C2','C3','C4']]

print(result)
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you very much furas for your work!! I did not expect that much help. I really appreciate it! That solves almost all the task I want to do :)

I didn't know the itertools.groupby() method.

Now I can work on length, if my dataset has values which are not 100 meters long.

Comment: if values are different then you may create column `df['LENGHT'] = df['END'] - df['START']` and later inside `for`-loop (when you work with `new_df`) you may try to `new_df.groupby('COLOR').sum()` and it should sum also `LENGHT` for every color - and this should be your value `C1`, `C2`, etc. Maybe later I will check it.

Comment: I added to full code `df['LENGTH'] = df['END'] - df['START']` and `count = new_df.groupby('COLOR')['LENGTH'].sum()` and now it calculate different than 100

Comment: Ah yes i also added `df['LENGHT']`, but i couldnt wrap my head around `new_df.groupby('COLOR')['LENGTH'].sum()`, now it all works. Thank you very much again!